# How to select all elements in different rows with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to select the components from the class 'thumbImg'. The website has 3 different rows and inside of the rows there are a few elements (those are the ones I want to get). My script is not working and I'm not sure why, it only returns an empty list without the information. Any help would be appreciated.

This is an esqueleton of what I have to scrape:

```
<div class="thumbnails">
   <div class="row-0">
       <div class="inside">
           <div class="thumbImg">
               <img src="...">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the code so far:

```
info = []
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[3]/div/div/div")
   
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
for e in elem:
   info.append(e)
```

This is the XPath that I copied from the source of the website but the last two are for the row and then for the element, that's why I didn't add it to my element:

```
//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]
```

Comment: It seems like maybe the element is in a shadow root or iframe, can you check?

Comment: @C.Peck It is inside a <div id="root">

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are 3 rows with `<div class="row-0">`, `<div class="row-1">`, `<div class="row-2">`

try this :

```
info = []
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("div.thumbnails div[class*='row']")
for e in elem:
     info.appende(e.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```